# Android contentprovider complex query involving 2 tables

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

How do I run this query in a contentprovider?

```
SELECT * FROM sms_data WHERE number != (SELECT DISTINCT number from test) AND time > ?
```

Comment: I think `<>` is used for `not equal to`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the query is probably wrong. Instead of `number != (...)` you likely want `number NOT IN (...)`.

Assuming `test` is a table in your app and not in the content provider, you can perform the query in two steps:

1. Subquery `SELECT DISTINCT number FROM test`. Build a comma-separated string such as `'12345','23456','45678'` from the results.
2. Do the content provider query with selection

   ```
   number NOT IN (<that comma-separated list>) AND time > ?
   ```

Comment: Please, do you think you could help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257416/android-how-can-i-pass-data-related-to-two-tables-to-a-the-insert-method-of-a?

Answer (score 1):

For a subquery you can use rawQuery() or [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Overriding onQuery method of ContentProvider, I managed to put this bunch of code that works well for me.

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case TABLE1:
            Cursor cursor = database.query("sms_data", projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cursor;
        case TABLE2:
            Cursor c = database.query(true, "test", projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, null);
            c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return c;
        case COMBINED:
            String sql = "SELECT " + appendColumns(projection) +
                    " FROM sms_data WHERE number != IFNULL((SELECT DISTINCT number FROM test), 'abc') AND "  +  selection;
            Cursor cur = database.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
            cur.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            return cur;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri + " Match = " + URI_MATCHER.match(uri));
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Remember that this works only for a single row in test table.